# Is there a business term for providing a level of support based on customer's worth?

Tags: customer-service

Some business provide better customer service/support(more frequent, faster responses) to their larger clients ( or those that spend more money).  Is there a business term for this?  Ie "volume based support"?

Comment: hi Jen. That doesn't seem to be question, relevant to Workplace. I can't think of any other relevant Stack, maybe English would be one. In any case, what problem are you trying to solve? In what context do you want to know it? these are all important points to ask a good question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on English Learning

Comment: @aaaaaa Maybe Economics.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean no, it does not "belong on English Learning" because it is in no way an ESL question, or even an English Language question, but rather a **business terminology question**.  Dumping questions on other sites where they are off topic is explicitly prohibited.

Comment: Opinions can vary, but I think this is better on the English Language site. I don’t know of a definitive term for this, but i’ve heard it referred to as tiered support or support levels. Personally, I like Joe’s comment better

Comment: @JoeStrazzere That term (to me) means "this customer has paid for better support", rather than inherently "this customer is larger so we're treating them better".

Comment: @berry120 there is "this customer is not paying anything yet but we need to keep them happy because they are Google/Apple/US government" situation. Anyways. OP should clarify context

Comment: @aaaaaa Exactly. I think that's what the OP is referring to, and I wouldn't class that as "premium level support".

Answer (score 3):

"Level of support" is described in terms of a "Service Level Agreement" (or SLA).  It sets customer expectations.  For example this is a SLA: "We accept requests for support by telephone or email. We acknowledge them within two business hours, and provide progress reports every business day until the problem is resolved."

Or, for a valuable high-revenue customer or prospective customer, you might say, "We offer support around the clock. We acknowledge all requests for support within ten minutes, and provide hourly updates."  (This kind of SLA is costly to provide.)

Smaller and newer companies often have not (yet) worked out the precise SLA they can offer.

Generically, a more rigorous SLA is often called, and sold as, "premium support." But your company may use some other brand name, like the "platinum plan," for example.

Ask somebody in your company what you call this.  If you are personally responsible for providing support, have a conversation about the SLA. It can be informal. But you need to know what it is to do your job effectively.

Comment: I think the question is really asking about if there is a term that encompasses the rationale for giving different customers different SLAs. Something that may dictate priority of support.

Comment: Our company also uses the SLA terminology but I think this all falls under the scope of stakeholder management.